# Cognos Report Studio vs Cognos Workspace Advanced

Tags: cognos

I recently started learning about Cognos and I am trying to decide if I can focus on learning one tool rather than both as they seem to have similar functionality.

**What are the differences between Cognos Report Studio and Cognos Workspace Advanced?**

**Are there some things that can be done in one but not the other?**

**Why do we need both tools?**

This [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.wig_cr.10.2.2.doc/c_gtstd_bia.html) says that there are "objects that can be inserted only in Report Studio, such as map." Those objects can be viewed but not edited in Workspace Advanced.

**Does this mean that Workspace Advanced is unfinished or that the mentioned "objects" are deprecated and should no longer be used?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognos Workspace Advanced is the logical upgrade path for IBM Cognos BI. It brings together Query Studio, Analysis Studio, and Report Studio Express features, all in one place. 
If you are working with IBM Cognos 8.x, you can continue to use your queries from IBM Cognos BI 8.x in IBM Cognos BI v10.x and newer; however if you plan to build new reports for query and analysis, it is recommended you can work with IBM Cognos Workspace Advanced.

Comment: I have been using Cognos 10.2.1 and 10.2.2 for several months now. I prefer Report Studio b/c it has more functionality than Workspace Advanced. Ironically, I think Workspace Advanced is probably better for less advanced users. I have not been able to find query studio features in Workspace Advanced.

Comment: Is your job related more towards a power user within a work group or a report/analytics developer?